# Query to find tool set and its elements in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am working on fetching all the element types under a tool set from Enterprise Architect through C # add-ins. Example: Actor, Collaboration, Collaboration Use, Test Case and Use Case are part of the UML::Use Case Toolset.

I tried by querying the tables t_objecttypes and t_diagramtypes. I am unable to  find a table in EA to list the available tool sets in EA and the element types under each tool set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find that info in the database, and there is nothing in the API that returns this info.

For the standard UML stuff that is hardcoded in EA.
For MDG's you can find the info in the MDG file (which is readable xml)

Comment: Thank you.I am able to fetch from xml for MDG. Kindly suggest if there are EA API that I can use to get all element types under a toolbox in EA or toolbox elements associated with a diagram type incase of UML types

Comment: No, there no API you can use. The only thing you can do is go over them one by one and write down what is in there.